# Error while running mapreduce program on hadoop using java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Hey guys I m following http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_mapreduce.htm . After running the program using this

```
hadoop jar units.jar hadoop.ProcessUnits input_dir output_dir
```

I m getting the following error:

> 16/09/04 20:32:14 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load
>   native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable
>
> 16/09/04 20:32:15 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
>
> 16/09/04 20:32:15 
>       INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
>
> 16/09/04 20:32:15 
>       INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
>
> 16/09/04
>   20:32:15 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line
>   option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute
>   your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
>
> 16/09/04 20:32:15 
>       INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser932260839/.staging/job_local932260839_0001
>   Exception in thread "main" ExitCodeException exitCode=1: chmod: cannot
>   access
>   `/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser932260839/.staging/job_local932260839_0001':
>   No such file or directory

Comment: Are you sure this is an error? These messages all look like info or warnings which may be ignored. If your program is not running as expected, what is it doing?

Comment: Ya m sure look at the end its showing an exception there...please help me out...there we have chmod cannot access 
Exception in thread "main" ExitCodeException exitCode=1: chmod: cannot access `/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser932260839/.staging/job_local932260839_0001': No such file or directory

Comment: INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser932260839/.staging/job_local932260839_0001 Exception in thread "main" ExitCodeException exitCode=1: chmod: cannot access `/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser932260839/.staging/job_local932260839_0001': No such file or directory

Comment: @vinith Were you able to solve this? I am facing something similar as per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002836/unable-to-submit-concurrent-hadoop-jobs

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the last few lines of the error that the java program you are running cannot access the folder /app/hadoop/...........

The Solution is to change ownership for the folder /app/hadoop like this:

`chown USER_NAME /app/hadoop`

Replace "USER_NAME" with your user name.
It Works fine!