# Unable to submit concurrent Hadoop jobs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am running `Hadoop 2.7` on my local machine, along with `HBase 1.4` and `Phoenix 4.15`. I have written an application which submits map reduce jobs that delete data in HBase through Phoenix. Each job is run by an individual thread of a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and looks like this:

```java
public class MRDeleteTask extends Task {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MRDeleteTask.class);
    private String query;
    public MRDeleteTask(int id, String q) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.query = q;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LOGGER.info("Running Task: " + getId());
        try {
            Configuration configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
            Job job = Job.getInstance(configuration, "phoenix-mr-job-"+getId());
            LOGGER.info("mapper input: " + this.query);
            PhoenixMapReduceUtil.setInput(job, DeleteMR.PhoenixDBWritable.class, "Table", QUERY);
            job.setMapperClass(DeleteMR.DeleteMapper.class);
            job.setJarByClass(DeleteMR.class);
            job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
            job.setOutputFormatClass(NullOutputFormat.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Writable.class);
            TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job);
            boolean result = job.waitForCompletion(true);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is fine if there is only 1 thread in the ThreadPoolExecutor. If more than one such Hadoop jobs are submitted concurrently, nothing happens. As per the logs, the error looks like:

```
4439 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  MRDeleteTask  - java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Unable to rename file: [/tmp/hadoop-user/mapred/local/1595274269610_tmp/tmp_phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.4-client.jar] to [/tmp/hadoop-user/mapred/local/1595274269610_tmp/phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.4-client.jar]

4439 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  MRDeleteTask  - java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: chmod: /private/tmp/hadoop-user/mapred/local/1595274269610_tmp/phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.4-client.jar: No such file or directory
```

The tasks are submitted using `ThreadPoolExecutor.submit()` and their status is being checked using the returned future `future.isDone()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jobs were not being submitted to YARN, but instead running locally from Intellij. Adding the following to the job configuration solved the issue:

```
conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
```